# What's the most efficient way of checking whether a string ends with a certain character with TCL?

Tags: tcl

I would like to check if this string pattern `"name.{j}.name.{i}.param"` ends with `"{i}.param"`

Comment: `regexp "{i}.param$"  "name.{j}.name.{i}.param"`?

Comment: `string match "*{i}.param" $string` -- http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm -- but I don't think you're asking the right question.

Comment: This isn't very different from your last question. Why don't you step back and think about describing what you're actually trying to do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most efficient techniques for doing this test are to use either `string match` or `regexp`. You can also use `string last` or `string range` and test that for equality.

Let's test!

**Setup**

```
% set str "name.{j}.name.{i}.param"
name.{j}.name.{i}.param
% set pat "{i}.param"
{i}.param
```

### Using `string match`

```
% string match *$pat $str
1
% time {string match *$pat $str} 10000
8.0875808 microseconds per iteration
```

Optimising by removing the pattern construction outside the timing loop:

```
% set glob *$pat
*{i}.param
% time {string match $glob $str} 10000
5.4690824000000005 microseconds per iteration
```

### Using `string last`

```
% expr {[string last $pat $str]==[string length $str]-[string length $pat]}
1
% time {expr {[string last $pat $str] == [string length $str]-[string length $pat]}} 10000
10.675282300000001 microseconds per iteration
```

OK, that was surprisingly slow. Let's try factoring out some of the computation:

```
% set len [expr {[string length $str] - [string length $pat]}]
14
% time {expr {[string last $pat $str] == $len}} 10000
6.8803367 microseconds per iteration
% time {expr {[string last $pat $str] == 14}} 10000 
6.835114999999999 microseconds per iteration
```

Faster, but not as fast as `string match`. Is slower on a long input string if the pattern is absent.

### Using `string range`

```
% time {expr {[string range $str end-[expr {[string length $pat]-1}] end] eq $pat}} 10000
11.9834488 microseconds per iteration
```

Optimising again by factoring out static computation:

```
% set idx end-[expr {[string length $pat]-1}]
end-8
% time {expr {[string range $str $idx end] eq $pat}} 10000
7.7081886 microseconds per iteration
% time {expr {[string range $str end-8 end] eq $pat}} 10000
7.261692600000001 microseconds per iteration
```

That's back in the ballpark, and will have performance that is consistent.

### Using `regexp`

Note that we need to do some work to prepare the regular expression, as it contains metacharacters yet we want to do an end-anchored match. This preparation step is itself costly.

```
% time {regexp [regsub -all {\W} $pat {\\&}]$ $str} 10000
24.428607500000002 microseconds per iteration
```

O! U! C! H!

Let's factor out the RE construction and retime:

```
% set RE [regsub -all {\W} $pat {\\&}]$
\{i\}\.param$
% regexp $RE $str
1
% time {regexp $RE $str} 10000
5.4204058 microseconds per iteration
```

Fast. But we needed that construction step done ahead of time.

## Summary

While using `regexp` is fast, it's actually tricky to use because of that preparation step, which is itself expensive. I advise the `string match` approach in normal use.

Comment: Note that the timings would have been faster if I'd been doing them in a procedure, as it allows variable accesses to be optimised, but getting good timings out of that is rather harder and the pattern of timings will probably be similar.

Comment: The similarity between the `string match` and `regexp` timing is also no coincidence:  the "simple enough" regexp is automatically translated to a glob.